# target all react components with a custom event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in React if I create my own component, or used some third party component, like:

```js
import { SomeComponent } form "library";
```

I want one target all instances of that component with an event, or css. like:

```js
document.getElementByTagName("MyOwnComponent").addEventListener (...)
// OR
document.getElementByTagName("SomeComponent").addEventListener (...)
```

is this possible? and, how to achieve it?

I tried to target every `Link` component, by putting this after body in index.html, since `Link` converts to `a` tag.

```js
          const allATags = [...document.getElementsByTagName("a")];
 
          allATags.forEach(function (aElement) {
            aElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
              console.log("fired form index.html");
               window.scrollTo(0,0);
              
            });
          });
```

basically, my problem with using  `Link` from `react-router-dom`, when clicking it, it's not scrolling to top.

I want to attach an event to every `Link` component to scroll to top after clicking.

I can add `onClick` prop. but it's been used 100s of times in the application, and I don't want to go to every single instance and add `onClick`.

Comment: You cannot use the DOM API to access React elements as such. Can you provide more information about what *exactly* you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you want to bind an event handler to every instance of a specific component, why do you not bind the handler inside the component itself?

Comment: basically, my problem with usin  Link from react-router-dom, when clicking it it's not scrolling to top.
I want to attach an event to every Link tag to scroll to top after clicking.

Comment: It seems you can just pass an `onClick={}` prop to the `Link` component. If you want to do this for every `Link` by default, wrap `Link` in your own component that does that.

Comment: ya, but it's been used 100s of times in the application, and I don't want to go to every single instance and add `onClick`.

Comment: As I said, you can wrap in in your own component. Then you only have to update the import path.